# Use self in ModelForm fields

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Formview and pass the pk to the ModelForm. In the ModelForm i am not able to use self.pk in the queryset i define for the field:

**views.py**

[...]

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    # Pass extra kwargs to DetailProductForm
    kwargs = super(DetailProduct, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update({'pk': self.kwargs['pk']})
    return kwargs
```

**forms.py**

```
class DetailProductForm(forms.ModelForm):


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # get the pk from the FormView at set it as self.pk
        self.pk = kwargs.pop('pk', None)
        super(DetailProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # use self.pk in my queryset (there are more fields who use self.pk, this is just one as an example)
    field = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Configuration.objects.filter(product__pk=self.pk), widget=forms.RadioSelect)


    class Meta:
        model = Configuration
        fields = ['field']
```

> NameError: name 'self' is not defined

How can i use self.pk for the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. I actually do not even need a ModelForm anymore.

```
class DetailProductForm(forms.Form):

    field = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None, widget=forms.RadioSelect)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.pk = kwargs.pop('pk', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['field'].queryset = Configuration.objects.filter(product__pk=self.pk))
```